# Assessing Server Redundancy and Failover

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

How can we conduct a comprehensive assessment of our server environment's redundancy, including both active and standby domain controllers, primary servers, and secondary servers? Are there specific tools or commands available to aid in evaluating server redundancy?

Furthermore, how can we provide documented evidence of the failover process operating correctly? Should we consider performing a test by disconnecting the primary server's network cable to verify the secondary server's seamless assumption of responsibilities?

In addition, what steps can we take to validate server redundancy and ensure the automatic takeover by the secondary server in case of a primary server disconnection?

Comment: Documentation is necessary for my organization to verify that the secondary domain controller automatically takes over the process when the primary domain controller fails. 

The same thing needs to be checked for historian servers, where data will switch to the secondary server if the primary server fails.                                                            

To demonstrate and document the correct configuration of the settings, I require a method, whether it's through command, physical disconnection, or any tools to be used to check it.

Comment: Is there a reason that you deleted the previous question, which was closed? https://serverfault.com/questions/1149531/assessing-server-redundancy-and-failover

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know is BCDR test. There are some BCDR standards out there.
https://www.bcmpedia.org/wiki/ISO22301